# Resource File Use

Tags: c#, winforms, resources

All, the question is a basic one. I have been loading all .png icon that I use in a complex UI as a resource. This means that the 'Resource' folder contains approx. 100-150 small .pngs. This works but should I be doing this and if not what should I be doing?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best practice for using resources in a WPF project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472284/best-practice-for-using-resources-in-a-wpf-project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well basically, if you think the images will change then store them outside a resource file. If they're going to be static over the lifetime of the application (or its version) then a resource file is fine